# Redux wisout server.js

Tags: redux, react-redux

Can I use Redux without without a server-sided implementation (server.js) with rendering on client-side only? The challenge is to rewrite a part of the web application without changing my current server settings (Apache + PHP).

Comment: You can use redux in many combinations. A very common one is react and react-redux. Fully clientsided global application state.

Answer (score 2):

`server.js` in the Redux examples is just for running a Webpack dev server for development convenience. It has nothing to do with Redux, just like Webpack, or Grunt, or Gulp, or npm have nothing to do with Redux. These are completely unrelated technologies.

You might find the [`counter-vanilla` example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter-vanilla/index.html) useful. It shows how Redux can be used without any build system at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redux basic example</title>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/redux@latest/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>
        Clicked: <span id="value">0</span> times
        <button id="increment">+</button>
        <button id="decrement">-</button>
        <button id="incrementIfOdd">Increment if odd</button>
        <button id="incrementAsync">Increment async</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <script>
      function counter(state, action) {
        if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
          return 0
        }
        switch (action.type) {
          case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1
          case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1
          default:
            return state
        }
      }
      var store = Redux.createStore(counter)
      var valueEl = document.getElementById('value')
      function render() {
        valueEl.innerHTML = store.getState().toString()
      }
      render()
      store.subscribe(render)
      document.getElementById('increment')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
          store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
        })
      document.getElementById('decrement')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
          store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })
        })
      document.getElementById('incrementIfOdd')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
          if (store.getState() % 2 !== 0) {
            store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
          }
        })
      document.getElementById('incrementAsync')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
            store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
          }, 1000)
        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```